# History of polar graphs

Tags: soft-question, math-history, polar-coordinates

I’m looking for information regarding the mathematicians who studied polar graphs like cochleoids and butterfly curves. Using the search engines of the internet, I got names but no actual information on them like John Perks for cochleoids and Temple H Fay for butterfly curves. Can someone give more details?

Comment: There's a bit [here](https://prabook.com/web/temple_h.fay/817340).  I got it by googling "Temple H Fay" **without** "butterfly curve".

Comment: Wolfram Mathworld ([here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cochleoid.html) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ButterflyCurve.html)) has information and references.

Comment: You can look up people at the Mathematics Genealogy Project, e.g. [Temple H Fay](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=1692), and on MathSciNet or [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Temple+H.+Fay&btnG=)